# stop function after x seconds angular 9

Tags: angular

i want to stop a function in 10000 seconds but this doesnt work on angular:

```html
setTimeout(() => {
        this
        .ngZone
        .run(() => {
            if (device.name.includes('DeviceName')) {
              this.connectToDevice(device)
            }
        });
       }, 10000,  console.log('not found'));
```

this start the function after 10000, but i need to stop the function after 10000 seconds and show a message..

Comment: What is `this.connectToDevice` ? How would you stop it at any given moment?

Comment: `clearTimeout(yourSetTimeoutVariable)`

Comment: CHeck This:https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use pipe with timeout from rxjs

> import { timeout } from 'rxjs/operators';

example:

```
your_subscription
  .pipe(timeout(10000)) // closed after 10 seconds
  .subscribe((result) => {
    // do stuff
  });
```